# Deploy WPF application using windows installer project with manifest file

Tags: wpf, windows-installer, manifest

I created a WPF application which creates some files locally. Now some files have a super long name and so I created a app.manifest file which contains the property 'longPathAware'. Now everything works when I launch my application using visual studio. But I'm using a **windows installer project** to deploy this to other PC's and now it seems that the app.manifest file is completely ignored.

Does anybody have any idea on how to do this? Is this even possible?
I've already changed 'Build action' and 'Copy to output directory' but this doesn't change anything.

Thanks for the help!

Kind regards,

Evert